# Add/Remove jQuery Validation Engine class dynamically

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-validation-engine

I'm using jQuery Validation Engine plugin to validate my form. According to a condition if it fails i have to remove the validation for one control and if it is success then i have to assign the validation or vice versa.

//Code:

Html:

```
 <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlTransporterType" class="validate[required]" onchange="disableCourier()">
         <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Text="OwnVehicle" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Text="Transporter" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Text="Courier" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
 </asp:DropDownList>


  <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlCourierId">
         <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Text="Professional" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Text="STCourier" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
  </asp:DropDownList>
```

Source from Browser:

Before assigning:

```
<select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlCourierId" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlCourierId">
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="1">Professional</option>
    <option value="2">STCourier</option>

</select>
```

After Assigning:

```
<select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlCourierId" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlCourierId" class="validate[required]">
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="1">Professional</option>
    <option value="2">STCourier</option>

</select>
```

Script:

```
function disableCourier() {

            var e = document.getElementById('<%= ddlTransporterType.ClientID%>');
            var f = document.getElementById('<%= ddlCourierId.ClientID%>');
            var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
         //   alert(strUser);
            if (strUser == 1 || strUser == 2){
                f.disabled = true;
                $('#<%= ddlCourierId.ClientID%>').removeClass("validate[required]");
                }
            else {
                f.disabled = false;
                $('#<%= ddlCourierId.ClientID%>').addClass("validate[required]");
            }
        }
```

The above code is not working, which means there is no error and when i checked with the inspect element the class is assigned but in the browser the validation is not working.

Any help/ideas?

Comment: [tag:jquery-validation-engine] and [tag:jquery-validate] are two totally different things.  Edited.  Also, please show the _rendered_ HTML code... after all, this question is about client-side code.

Comment: Those are the HTML code for which i validate.

Comment: That's not the _rendered_ HTML.  "Rendered" HTML is what you see in the browser, not what you upload to your server.

Comment: @Sparky: Updated my ques. Kindly look into this.